# Laravel React Vite Tailwind Css not loading the Css, logo and some components

Tags: css, reactjs, laravel, tailwind-css, vite

I have laravel project which is already running with blade views and api with JWT authentication.

Now decided to move views using React. So downloaded the Midone Enigma React theme. While integrating the react theme to existing application. css, logo and some component are not loading.

Below is my vite.config.js

```
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
// import reactRefresh from '@vitejs/plugin-react-refresh';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import sassPlugin from 'vite-plugin-sass';
import path from "path";

export default defineConfig(({ command }) => ({
  base: command === 'serve' ? '' : '/build/',
  publicDir: 'fake_dir_so_nothing_gets_copied',
  build: {
    manifest: true,
    sourcemap: true,
    outDir: 'public/build',
    rollupOptions: {
      input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
    },
    commonjsOptions: {
      include: ["tailwind.config.js", "node_modules/**"],
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    // reactRefresh(),
    react(),
    laravel({
      input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
      refresh: true,
    }),
    sassPlugin(),
  ],
  esbuild: {
    jsxFactory: 'React.createElement',
    jsxFragment: 'React.Fragment',
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "tailwind-config": path.resolve(__dirname, "./tailwind.config.js"),
    },
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: ["tailwind-config"],
  },
}));
```

I am using laravel version 10. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Got resolved. There is another framework (primereact) previously installed.  After removing that got css, components and logo.

Answer (score -2):

It seems that there might be some misconfigurations or missing dependencies causing the CSS, logo, and components not to load properly. Let's go through some troubleshooting steps to identify and fix the issue:

1. Double-check file paths for CSS, logo, and components in React
   components.
2. Verify assets are bundled correctly during Vite build (check output
   directory).
3. Ensure proper import statements for CSS, images, and components in
   React components.
4. Confirm Tailwind CSS integration and avoid conflicting custom
   styles.
5. Check browser console for error messages.
6. Install all required dependencies for React, Vite, and Tailwind CSS.
7. Refer to the Midone Enigma React theme documentation for specific
   integration steps.
8. Consider using laravel-mix for asset compilation if issues persist.

Comment: Thanks. My console did not throws error. After npm run build. all css and js are in public/build folder. And that also loaded in browser.

Comment: 10 answers, some of them lengthy, with an average interval of less than 11 minutes looks like the typical [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) workflow. [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76785242/can-we-control-js-with-the-help-of-css-properties-is-that-possible/76785504#76785504) had the slip-up *"my last update in September 2021"*.